# I want to Get all the SharePoint 365 users for the SharePoint Online Tenant

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

I want to fetch all the users details from the Office365.

I want to create one Timer job which will run using Tenant administrator and it will then fetch all the users available in that particular tenant and store it somewhere

I am stuck in an approach i need to take.

Can some please guide me with an example for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Graph API to retrieve all Office 365 accounts from your tenant.
You will find solution in thisa answer: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/168701/how-can-i-get-all-users-who-have-access-to-office-365

Comment: Hi Sprey thanks for the comment. What I wanted to achieve is I got it working.One more thing I wanted to achieve is I want to login without Customer or User Interaction . how can i do that?

Comment: If you mean without user interaction at all, maybe you should consider using the app-only approach: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_only. This way you define application that has access to your tenant, and grant it permissions (at the end of the link you can see that you can grant it rights to access all users full profiles). Regards